# Korea root meanings: 작다 - small 적다 - to be few

Tags: vocabulary, translation, meaning, difference, phrase-meaning

Is there a relationship between these two words (since they sound similar)? I always try to look at roots , meanings, and suffixes, like I do in other languages. Or is this just a coincidence ?

작다 - small

적다 - to be few?

Comment: As a Korean, I think you are 100% correct. The pronuciation is related I think no coincident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

적다 means a few, a little.  It can apply to a small amount of anything (countable or not doesn't matter).

To Koreans, 작다 and 적다 are very close concepts since a little or a few of something will have a small volume or count, so it's no coincidence that the two words sound similar.  There are cases where you can even use the two interchangeably, like 작은 양 and 적은 양.  적은 양 would be the correct way but if you want to emphasize the visual aspect of it, you might use 작은 양.  The point is: 작은 and 적은 are almost like two sides of the same concept.